# Amazon SES for sendmail in ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, amazon-ec2, sendmail, amazon-ses

i tried to use Amazon SES with sendmail on my ubuntu server for sending mail because EC2 ips are blacklisted and i followed the following tutorial

http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/index.html?InitialSetup.EmailVerification.html

But its not working don't know why please help me

Answer (score 4):

Amazon just released SMTP access to SES and it's not too difficult to setup now.  I whipped up a quick howto this morning:
http://www.millcreeksys.com/2011/12/14/how-to-configure-your-postfix-server-to-relay-email-through-amazon-simple-email-service-ses/

Comment: Very helpful, thanks for taking the time to write your article!

Answer (score 2):

Did you request [production access](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/index.html?InitialSetup.Customer.html) ? If not you may only send email from **and to** verified email addresses.

Answer (score 1):

This has been improved by AWS. Go here for setup instructions: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/sendmail.html

Then PHP and other languages can simply use sendmail out of the box.